# Trouble uploading json file with flask

Tags: python, json, flask, file-upload

For some reason, this won't accept json files.

```
@app.route('/get_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    dataFile = request.files['file_path']
    dataFileName = dataFile.filename
    dataFile.save(os.path.join(uploads_dir, dataFileName))
```

I keep getting this error:

[image]

Comment: that seems to be in the front end; check the file upload dialog/thing settings

Comment: @Pat-Laugh it was a front-end issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have `json` set as an file ending in your template by `<input type="file" accept="json">`. (The template is not supplied so I can't pinpoint the line. This is not an error of the backend (flask) but of the your template code (jinja/html). It would be nice if you could supply a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for such issues.

For more information about `<input type="file">` take a look at the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#attr-accept).

Example of correct `accept`:

```html
<input type="file" accept=".json">
```

This will only allow `*.json` file but keep in mind that users may supply other files manually and create a fallback or validation when parsing/ saving the file.

Comment: You're totally right, it was a front end issue. There was a list of acceptable extensions that I had to add json to. Thank you sm and I'll keep in mind adding an MRE for the future!

Comment: @Mehak Would you mind marking this answer as correct to close this question or are there other related problems?